# How Can I Ring Every User in a Twilio SIP Domain

Tags: twilio, sip

I've created a SIP Domain in Twilio, created the Credentials List and added two users. I've registered two SIP phones with the SIP Domain and using a webhook I'm able to place calls to these numbers by returning the following TwiML:

```
<Response>
    <Dial answerOnBridge="true">
        <Sip>
            user@my-uri.sip.us1.twilio.com
        </Sip>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

The problem here is that only a single phone will ring at a time. How can I return a response that causes every user in the SIP Domain to ring?

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you cannot use Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) to simultaneously ring multiple SIP end-points, unless the SIP end-points register using the the same Username (Address of Record/AOR), then you can have up to 10 registered.

You would need to use the REST API and place multiple calls to the [Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource), to generate simultaneous calls to the SIP end-points. Twilio by default provides 1 Call Per Second (CPS), but this can be increased by working with Twilio sales.

**UPDATE**

GA

[Two More Reasons to Use Twilio Programmable Voice with Your SIP Network](https://www.twilio.com/blog/blind-transfer-sip-multidial-programmable-voice)